# Regex for Gitlab CI Test coverage parsing

Tags: gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

I have been struggling to find a regular expression that will work in the "Test coverage parsing" input on the "CI/CD Pipelines" page. It doesn't help that the examples show inconsistent examples, i.e. some escape parenthesis and other don't, same with percent symbols, some capture the explicit result in `$1`, etc. Anyway, here is my text - whats the regex?

CI Badge:

```
![coverage](https://gitlab.com/mycompany/master/badges/master/coverage.svg?job=coverage)
```

Output text:

```
Unit test coverage:
   10.01% blocks
   10.01% lines
```

Tried so far: (added the slashes simply to represent the space at front or regex)

```
/ \(\d+\.\d+\%\) blocks/
/ (\d+\.\d+\%) blocks/
/ (\d+\.\d+%) blocks/
/ (\d+\.\d+)% blocks/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the coverage URL query "?job=coverage" was incorrect. As for the regex, I used:

```
\W(\d+(?:\.\d+)%)\sblocks
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a useful Ruby regex web page.

http://www.rubular.com/

I didn't not help for me with my GitLab code coverage parsing. I think it is because there seems to be a bug registered for a regex problem in GitLab.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21495

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This regex should grab the blocks coverage:

```
^\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\s*blocks
```

If you want to grab the line coverage instead then use this:

```
^\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\s*lines
```

GitLab adds the leading and trailing `/` automatically so you don't need to add them to your regex.

For future reference, GitLab is written in Ruby so you can test this regular expression in Ruby over at [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/9dRCVMSFtA)

Comment: I think you can improve it a bit by making it slightly more flexible - match any whitespace instead of just spaces, make the whitespace optional (the "blocks" or "lines" keyword is what matters), escape the decimal dot and match percentage displayed without decimal digits. http://rubular.com/r/7m5Z48JRcQ

Comment: @tmt I've updated my answer to use some of your suggestions.

Comment: This regex didn't work for me. Specifically what is supposed to be captured? Should it be the decimal, i.e. "10.01", or the percent, i.e. "10.01%" or something more? The regex provided by @BrokenBinary has multiple captures.

Comment: It should capture the decimal number and the percent sign, `10.01%`, or a whole number and the percent sign, `95%`.

Comment: Also, it only has one capture group. The `(?: )` group is a non-capturing group, as denoted by the `?:` at the beginning of it.